# Duplicated account - unable to sign in

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, user-accounts

I'm quite active in the web section of StackOverflow. When I went to support the Area 51 [Web Design proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647/web-designing) I unknowingly "committed" on an unregistered account.

After having committed, upon seeing I only showed 1 total rep showing, I attempted to login using the email form provided. I entered the same email as my SO (and all my SE sites) account, but it sent me a confirmation email.

But now the account is confirmed separately from my other SE accounts. Can I get the new account deleted? Shouldn't it detect if I already have a SE account when I input my email?

[The dupe account](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/114948/zach-saucier)

---

Aside: Also, when going on to the Area 51 Q&A it says I have only 1 rep and shows a red "Finish signing up for your account" banner at the top of the page. When I click the link to finish signing up, it directs me to [this page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/authenticate) but gives me an "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" error

---

In short, can someone please combine the Area51 profile with my SE account (or delete it so I can create it the correct way) and can we get this bug prevented by checking to see if an inputted email is in use?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Also that form deals with dupe accounts on a certain SE website, not across two (I am unable to create one on Area51 with my SE profile)

Comment: Oh boy, Area 51 strikes again.

Comment: Retracting my CV since its clear it's not a dup

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your A51 profile was linked to the correct network account, but you *also* ended up with another account that had the Area 51 Discuss profile attached to it. I merged the two accounts and you should be all set now.

I'll need to look at how/why one can create an unregistered profile on A51 Discuss and either disable that or at least suppress that overhead banner that redirects to what A51 Discuss thinks is its parent SE site (Area 51)... which is an old fork of the codebase and doesn't behave at all the same as the rest of our sites. (This is why you get an error page when trying to follow the "finish signing up" link.) Fun times for everybody.

Comment: One last thing. On [the proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58647?page=1&phase=commitment&committers=totalreputation#tab-top) that I committed to, it is using my Area51 rep as opposed to my SO rep (which it seems to be using for others). Any way to fix this?

Comment: @ZachSaucier That's (probably) just a matter of caching. Give it a few days and if it doesn't update on its own, let me know.

Comment: Now it seems that any time I sign up on a new SE site it creates a new section and doesn't recognize the other account. For example, I just created [this Data.SE profile](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/211122/average-answer-length-of-a-user?UserId=2065702) and it is not linked to my others. Shall I open a new question?

Comment: @ZachSaucier The Data Explorer isn't a Q&A site. It's not actually aware of any of your profiles here and vice versa.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the information!

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269036/i-cant-log-in) the same case, or something else?