# Unable to create or log out of Area51 account

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login, user-accounts

My problem is very similar to [Duplicated account - unable to sign in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236423/duplicated-account-unable-to-sign-in)

On Area51, it shows me logged in as user117753 and keeps prompting me to visit my user page to set my name and email. I've tried logging out of another Stack Exchange site and clearing my *.stackexchange.com cookies but the problem still persists. There does not appear to be a log out for user117753 (presumably because the account isn't fully created yet?)

I'm able to log in to Area51 with my StackExchange account in Incognito mode but not with any browser for which I'm already logged into another Stack Exchange site.

How can I log out of the user117753 account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I merged your accounts, so you should be getting logged into the correct one now. Can you let me know if that's the case? Thanks!

Comment: It works now, thanks! :-D

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Awesome. :)