# I can't log in!

Tags: support, area-51, login, my-logins

I have an account I accidentally created on Area 51. I want to use *this* account, however.

It won't let me post on A51 Discussions for some reason, and I can't sign in on this account. Can that account, [Noah Simon](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/145162/noah-simon), be deleted?

Comment: Well, appears to be same case as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236423/duplicated-account-unable-to-sign-in). Hopefully, Anna (or other dev) will come over and merge your accounts.

Comment: Your A51 profile is linked to the same network account as your profile here on meta. What problems are you experiencing, exactly? If you can't post on Discuss, screenshots of what you're seeing on Discuss and on A51 would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No problem. More users accidentally create duplicate accounts. There are three things you can do:

1. Delete the account. If you want to delete your account follow the steps here: [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/245360). If you didn't use that account yet, you should be able to self-delete it from your profile. Else, see the post for steps to do.
2. Merge the accounts. If you do have contributions you want to be merged with this account, follow the steps described in [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/245360).
3. If you can't follow these steps, contact the SE team by clicking on Contact Us at the bottom of this page.